I am new to ubuntu and i am trying to install but it does not work after I write sudo apt update or sudo apt install some errors appears
I am new to ubuntu and i am trying to install but it does not work fter I write sudo apt update or sudo apt install some errors appears and i dont know what it means.Please help
These are the errors:
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_groovy-jammy.list (Component)
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/ cloud-sdk: /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.

➜  ~ sudo apt insall wine64
E: Invalid operation insall

What's the problem? What should I do?

After  you fix your system, don't follow instructions on some webpage or video to install wine. Just install the version from the Ubuntu repos.

Your error tells you that you have an error on line 1 ("Malformed entry 1 in list file" in the file specified (/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_groovy-jammy.list) added by a user on your system with sudo rights.. That line needs to be corrected (subsequent lines were not read; it stopped at the bad line, so check the whole file).

@guiverc i tried that,but it s still not working

How do i correct the line,is only one,what can be wrong with sudo apt update?

We're limited to details you provide in your question; I can't see what is in that file unless you provide a copy of it.  I'll suggest following advice @OrganicMarble already suggested & use the official Ubuntu packages that don't require adding 3rd party sources (you'll have less problems that way)   As for removing that line.. see duplicate.. Myself I'd use an editor (vi actually) bu that editor is far from user-friendly (it's from before arrow keys on terminals!)  but if you're using a desktop system (you don't specify and we're limited to what you tell us) GUI tools can be used too

That was all i wrote

sudo apt update [sudo] password for   :  E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_groovy-jammy.list (Component) E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/ cloud-sdk: /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg !=  E: The list of sources could not be read. ➜  ~  

As already stated, the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_groovy-jammy.list contains an error on line 1 of that file.  Refer prior comments & duplicate link, or official docs at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu  (You tags highlight a Server system so no GUI, but you also tagged gnome-terminal which only runs on Desktop installs so your system is unclear)

@guiverc that tag does not matter,i just put it to have 5 tags ,ignore that

Please edit your question (do not reply in comments) and show the entire contents of /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_groovy-jammy.list

The message you posted indicates that a third-party repository is wrongly configured.
The quick fix would be to remove the additional repo-file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_groovy-jammy.list.
Whatever you tried to installed here (I guess Wine) failed somehow and additional information are needed to get an correct answer here.

How do i remove that because its the only line that i have: sudo apt update

use files (nautilus) go to the directory they point you to see if there is such file. If there is you have to remove it through terminal.

And btw if the answer solves your problem pls accept it,
